# How to make an array.length counter update on user scroll using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a simple counter in the bottom of my app like this one:

[image: counter image]

And it is very simple atm, 80 is my array.length that is being populated through my axios request.

```
<div>{people.length.toLocaleString()}</div>
```

And as I scroll down the page, using `react-infinite-scroll`, the number goes up and up and this is just fine. What I'm trying to do is subtract the number as the user goes back up the page.

Is this something harder than I'm thinking? If so, don't give me the full answer, just give me the path to follow. Thanks.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish: https://mkorostoff.github.io/hundred-thousand-faces/

Comment: If the you want the counter not to reflect to total number of items retrieved via axios, but instead the item which they currently have scrolled onto the page, you're likely going to have to delve into the unpleasant business of using some vanilla DOM API to detect which item is currently onscreen.  Perhaps somebody else can think of a better approach.  You might consider seeking an open source library to help you achieve this, as it could get a bit messy with considering edge cases and browser support.

Answer (score 1):

you can do by using scroll event with `window.innerHeight` and the element bottom height to check whether its available inside the display window.

You can try like this using onscroll event which is available in library itself.

```js
let counter = 0;
 [listofElement].find(ele => {
  var conditionHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var cordinat = ele.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  counter++;
  return conditionHeight < cordinat;
});
```

You can check here with sample working part.

[image: Edit rough-violet-1qysy]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Your answers seems to be what I need but I'm having some trouble to convert it to hooks. Can you help me and then I can choose your answer as winner? https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-perlman-xgxgw?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Issue is your using counter variable as Reference and the element counter, change the variable name in anyone place, it will work. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-haze-ewmnu

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the page you've linked, the code uses this function to get the size of the page:

```
function getScrollPercent() {
  var face_width = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
  var face_height = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
  var body = document.documentElement || document.body;
  var faces_per_row = Math.floor(main.clientWidth / face_width);
  var total_height = total / faces_per_row * face_height;
  var scroll_percent = (body.scrollTop - main.offsetTop + body.clientHeight) / total_height;
  var count = Math.floor(scroll_percent * total);

  var chunked_count = count - (count % faces_per_row);

  if (chunked_count > 0) {
    counter.classList = "fixed";
  }
  else {
    counter.classList = "";
  }
  return (chunked_count > 0) ? chunked_count : 0;
}
```

The essential bit is `var scroll_percent = (body.scrollTop - main.offsetTop + body.clientHeight) / total_height;`. Basically, if you can calculate your total height (assuming that isn't infinite), then you can use `body.clientHeight`, +/- offsets, divided by `totalHeight` to figure out how far down the page you are. Call this from an event listener on `scroll`, and you should be good to go.

Incidentally, if [this](https://github.com/guillaumervls/react-infinite-scroll) is the infinite scroll library you're talking about using, it's no longer maintained in favor of [react-infinite-scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller).

Comment: Can you reproduce in react? I was not able to

Answer (score 0):

using `react-infinite-scroll`, you can't back axios request results or remove generated doms.

The solution is calculating width and height of every doms and calculate offset.

Check how many doms are above the scrollReact and so so.